# How to set ActionMailer SMTP Settings outside the Environment Config Files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have the settings for my action_mailer.smtp_settings stored in my DB. Obviously I can't load those into my production.rb or development.rb environment config files. Is there any way I can set those in my ApplicationMailer class?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You could do something like this in your mailer:

```
delivery_options = { user_name: company.smtp_user,
                     password: company.smtp_password,
                     address: company.smtp_host }
mail(to: @user.email,
     subject: "Please see the Terms and Conditions attached",
     delivery_method_options: delivery_options)
```

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-emails-with-dynamic-delivery-options

Hope it helps!